# Горячий BACKUP БД Oracle с помощью RMAN

Tags: oracle, rman

Суть проблемы такова, нужно сделать полный BACKUP и перенести этот BACKUP на другую машину и развернуть там, думаю RMAN какраз для этих целей. Но когда я пишу

`BACKUP DATABASE;`

получаю вот такую ошибку:

> RMAN> BACKUP DATABASE ;
>
> Starting backup at 30-OCT-17 using channel ORA_DISK_1 channel
>
> ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set channel ORA_DISK_1:
>
> specifying datafile(s) in backup set RMAN-03009: failure of backup
>
> command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 10/30/2017 11:20:41 ORA-19602:
>
> ?????????? ?????????????/?????????? ???????? ???? ? ??????
>
> NOARCHIVELOG continuing other job steps, job failed will not be re-run
>
> channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set channel
>
> ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set including current
>
> control file in backup set including current SPFILE in backup set
>
> channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 30-OCT-17 channel ORA_DISK_1:
>
> finished piece 1 at 30-OCT-17 piece
>
> handle=/home/oracle/app/flash_recovery_area/ZXP/backupset/2017_10_30/o1_mf_ncsnf_TAG20171030T112040_dzfvqbjq_.bkp
>
> tag=TAG20171030T112040 comment=NONE channel ORA_DISK_1: backup set
>
> complete, elapsed time: 00:00:01 RMAN-00571:
>
> =========================================================== RMAN-00569: 
>   =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS
>
> =============== RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at
>
> 10/30/2017 11:20:41 ORA-19602: ?????????? ?????????????/??????????
>
> ???????? ???? ? ?????? NOARCHIVELOG

Как исправить данную ошибку ? Помогите пожалуйста. Спасибо

Comment: @Mike А включить логирование для дальнейшей приятной работы с бекапами можно как-то ?

Comment: @Mike Понял, спасибо. А не могли бы вы ответом оформить что нибудь ? Можно на примере первого комент. и я закрою тему. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Если у вас лоализированые сообщения, то настраивайте также  консоль. Как вы понимаете все эти "????????"?

Comment: @0xdb если честно я знаю как менять кодировку на Win но не знаю как поменять её на CentOS7 добавить кодировку через правую кнопку мыши не помогает, я все перепробовал. Может вы подскажите мне пожалуйста ?

Comment: Попробуйте `declare -x LANG="ru_RU"` или посмотрите [тут](https://serverfault.com/questions/275403/how-do-i-change-my-locale-to-utf-8-in-centos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Горячий бекап средствами RMAN невозможен при работе БД в режиме NOARCHIVELOG. В этом режиме возможен только холодный бекап выполнением в RMAN следующих команд (команды можно записать в отдельный файл и подавать rman параметром):

```
connect target;
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
backup database;
alter database open;
```

Если же вы хотите настроить горячий бекап, то вам надо сначала убедится, что [flash_recovery_area](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/setup005.htm) правильно настроена. Посмотреть текущие настройки можно запросом `SELECT * FROM V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST`. Изменить местоположение этой области на диске можно командой `ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST = '/путь/к/flash_recovery_area'`. Рекомендуется её держать на другом физическом диске нежели файлы БД. Далее нам надо определиться с максимальным размером этой области. Я рекомендую минимальный объем в 3 полных размера всей базы данных. Потому что для гарантии восстановления БД в любой момент времени у нас должно быть место как минимум под 2 полных бекапа БД плюс место для хранения архивных журналов с момента самого первого хранящегося полного бекапа. Внимание: недостаток места на flesh_recovery_area приведет к невозможности записи архивного журнала и остановке базы данных. Изменить размер области можно с помощью `ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE = 10G`. После этих настроек можно перевести базу данных в режим ARHIVELOG (выполнять можно в sqlplus --nolog):

```
connect sys/password as sysdba;
shutdown IMMEDIATE;
startup mount EXCLUSIVE;
ALTER DATABASE archivelog;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```

После этого надо настроить периодические бекапы в виде запуска rman с файлом команд примерно такого содержания:

```
connect target;
delete obsolete;
backup current controlfile;
backup database;
exit;
```

Тут мы сначала удаляем совсем старые бекапы. После этой команды rman оставляет на диске один самый последний полный бекап и все логи после него (так что даже если в этот момент что то пойдет не так, мы всегда можем восстановиться). Следующие команды выполняют бекап контрол-файла и полный бекап БД. Текущий и предудущий бекапы со всеми логами я предпочитаю хранить. При желании можно настроить копирование всех файлов на удаленное файловое хранилище.