# RMAN - резервное копирование

Tags: oracle, rman

```
rman target user/11;
shutdown immediate
startup mount
alter database open;
backup full database;
```

Обваливается на последней строчки.
Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чем проблема?

Comment: ваша БД находится в режиме `NOARCHIVELOG`, надо перевести бд в `ARCHIVELOG`. https://www.imans.ru/8-oracle-database/14-vklyuchenie-rezhima-archivelog.html

Comment: Только включить нужно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Горячий BACKUP БД Oracle с помощью RMAN](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737796/%d0%93%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b9-backup-%d0%91%d0%94-oracle-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-rman)

Answer (score 0):

Горячий бекап средствами RMAN невозможен при работе БД в режиме NOARCHIVELOG. В этом режиме возможен только холодный бекап выполнением в RMAN следующих команд (команды можно записать в отдельный файл и подавать rman параметром):

```
connect target;
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
backup database;
alter database open;
```

Если интересно, [почитайте это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737796/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-backup-%D0%91%D0%94-oracle-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-rman). Удачи